# Get monk to play well with Q.all

Tags: node.js, promise

I have a collection of posts and a collection of users. When returning the list of posts, I want to resolve the references to users. This means making an async call for every row of the users. When monk returns a promise, it returns something that responds to "complete" or "success". Q expects something responding to "then". I need to use Q.all to wait for all the users to be fetched into the posts, but I can't make it play well with monk's promise style.

Here is my attempt.

```
exports.posts = function (req, res) {
    req.posts.find()
      .complete(function(err, posts) {
        handle(err, res, posts);
        var postsWithUsers = posts.map(function(post) {
          return req.users.findOne({_id: post.userId}).complete(function(err, result) {
            post.user = result;
          });
        });
        Q.all(postsWithUsers.map(function(monkPromise) {
          monkPromise.then = monkPromise.complete
        }), function(err, results) {
          console.log("done with all posts");
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for everyone else out there. This is one solution, perhaps not the best.

```
exports.posts = function (req, res) {
    req.posts.find()
      .complete(function(err, posts) {
        handle(err, res, posts);
        var postsWithUsers = posts.map(function(post) {
          var deferred = Q.defer();
          return req.users.findOne({_id: post.userId}).complete(function(err, result) {
            post.user = result;
            deferred.resolve(result);
          });
          return deferred.promise;
        });
        Q.all(postsWithUsers, function(err, results) {
          console.log("done with all posts");
        });
    });
```